# Extract repeating structure from an image

Tags: image-processing

I want to find repeating structures from the image .But I have no idea how to do it.Please help me.Actually i want to find how many lines and oval shapes look like similar and mark these by separate color.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to distinguish the wavy lines from the straight ones? Can they be interleaved; or are they always oriented as depicted?

Answer (score 2):

You want to detect two things: lines/curves and circles. There are well-known algorithms to do both, so let's find them separately. I will present a solution in Mathematica. You can translate to your language.

1. The first step is to eliminate the background. We do this by finding the background: 
   `img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olczj.jpg"]
   bimg = ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"]
   Blur[Closing[bimg, 20], 15]`

[image: background]

Then dividing by it:

> evenImg = Image[ImageData@bimg/ImageData@Blur[Closing[bimg, 20], 10]]

[image: even image]

2. Detect the edges:

> binImg = EdgeDetect[evenImg, 1, .1]

[image: Edges]

Now we just need to fill in the strokes:

> smImg = ImageResize[Dilation[binImg, 2], {500}]

[image: dilated]

3. We are finally ready for some detection. Let's start with the lines/curves:

> Show[smImg, 
>    Graphics[{Yellow, Thick, Line /@ ImageLines[smImg, 0.25]}]]

[image: Line detection]

4. What about the circles? Let's start by looking at all the connected components:

> morph = MorphologicalComponents@smImg; Colorize@morph

[image: Components]

The circles are there, all right. We just need to filter out the objects that are not circular. We can do this by looking at the circularity, elongation, [eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_%28mathematics%29), or [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic). Circles are easy to distinguish from other shapes by these properties.

```
noncircles = #[[1]] & /@ ComponentMeasurements[morph, "Elongation", # > 0.3 &]
circles = morph /. x_ :> 0 /; MemberQ[noncircles, x] // 
  Colorize // RemoveBackground
```

[image: Circles]

Comment: How can I do that command by using matlab?                                 Show[smImg, Graphics[{Yellow, Thick, Line /@ ImageLines[smImg, 0.25]}]],Please help me

Comment: It's just for superposing the lines on the original images, so you'd probably use [imfuse](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfuse.html)

Comment: Thanks.I am trying to implement the algorithm in matlab. Still struggling..Thank you.

Comment: The path to enlightenment is not without struggle :) [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/object-analysis.html) are the relevant MATLAB functions.